# Is there a way to NOT repeat styles when using @media?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm not sure if I'm asking this question right, but couldn't think of a better wording. I am playing with a new responsive bootstrap layout, one with a fixed collapsable side menu. You know, because it's the new black.

Anyway, I setup an `@media (max-width: 767px) {...}` in my css and threw in some stuff to adjust the workspace around when the screen is resized. That works. Then I decided to add a button to manually toggle even if the screen was over 767px, cause... choice.

But I found myself having to repeat all the styles I put in the @media block. And that seems dumb to me, because if I tweak some numbers I'll have to tweak in several places. But I can't seem to come up with how to organize it to not repeat.

Am I missing something? Or is this where I need to relent and start using LESS or some such?

Here is a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/yn5n9/ 
(note: to get the fiddle working the 'result' pane needs to be bigger than 767px).

notice in the @media there is this:

```
aside {...}
.main-container {...}
#sidebar-header {...}
```

but then to get the toggle button working I have these (with the same definitions):

```
.hide-it aside {...}
.hide-it .main-container {...}
.hide-it #sidebar-header {...}
```

triggered by `$('body').toggleClass("hide-it")`

Thanks.

Comment: A quick dirty way would be to add the class `hide-it` when the screen is resized (by stalking the resize event in Javascript), and so get rid of media queries. But I would like to see better answers than this one :-)

Comment: This whole thing reads as a plea for a reason to not use that thing that lets you use variables, even though you would really like to use variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No way to do this with current CSS3 specs, although the upcoming CSS variables might do the trick in the near future. You're stuck with LESS/SASS/etc.

BTW, I'm assuming JavaScript is not an option.

Comment: This is what I was expecting. I was using this layout more as a learning tool, as I'm new to 'responsive' & @media stuff and am trying to piece it altogether. I'm not against a javascript way or LESS way of doing things, but it just seemed sooo close but not quite I was hoping I missed something.